# I just installed Ubuntu 12.04, but I can't connect to WIFI

Tags: 12.04, wireless, iwlwifi

I can connect through Ethernet, but not wirelessly.

Can someone please direct me on what to do or where to get the drivers?  I have an HP Pavilion AMD Quadcore with Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter.  I've installed all the updates, but it still doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Kendor. I will purchase a usb dongle or the internal card.  Do you know if the Intel Centrino will work with HP?

Comment: Check this Solution


  http://askubuntu.com/questions/432053/how-to-enable-wifi-in-dell-5520-on-ubuntu-12-04-32-64-bit

Answer (score 0):

If you google the Realtek RTL8188 you will see that lots of people have problems with it, regardless of the kernel and drivers. You might have to spend a lot of energy to get it to work. In my case, I was able to connect with that card, but performance was very poor and there were lots of disconnects (it was unusable).

I initially tried an external USB dongle (Panda Ultra Wireless-N), which immediately solved the problem. I then eBayed an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 and just swapped out my internal card with it... have had no problems since. The cards are inexpensive ~$10 US on Amazon)...